# Series expansion of a function

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

How to expand
\begin{align*} y^{n} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(y-c)^{2}}
\end{align*}
in infinite series? Please help me for this.The series exansion of 
\begin{align*}
y^{n} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}y^{2}}
\end{align*}
is possible but I can not find for the above function.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\exp(i(y-c)^2)=\exp(iy^2-2icy)\cdot\exp(ic^2)$ and
$$\exp(uy^2+vy)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}(uy^2+vy)^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}y^k(uy+v)^k= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_ky^k$$
where 
$$a_k=\sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor} \frac{{k-r\choose r}u^rv^{k-2r}}{(k-r)!}$$
(because ${k-r\choose r}u^rv^{k-2r}$ is the summand of $y^r$ in $(uy+v)^{k-r}$).